# Solving Second Order ODE's in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to model the equation y" + 4y = 0, with initial conditions y(0) = 1 and y'(0) = 0, in Matlab. The snippet of code below shows a working approximation of the position as a function of time for the above ODE:

```
clear      
syms y(t)

%Differential Equation Conversion
P = odeToVectorField(diff(y, 2) == -4*y);
M = matlabFunction(P,'vars',{'t','Y'});

%Position Approximation
pos_solution = ode45(M,[0 20],[1 0]);
x = linspace(0,20,1000);
y = deval(pos_solution,x,1);

%Plot of Position as a function of time
figure(3)
plot(x,y,'b');
```

I am trying to take this data produced and find the velocity of the system as a function of time, but have no idea how to do so. Any help with this would be  appreciated.

Comment: "the waveform approximation for the velocity of the system" ... I don't know what this is nor what `y` represents.

Comment: `y = deval(pos_solution,x,1);` returns the integral of y', i.e., y (or position if `y` represents that). If you want y' (velocity if y represents position, the integral of y''), then use `y = deval(pos_solution,x,2);` as per the documentation. Or just use `y = deval(pos_solution,x);` to return both together.

Comment: Thank you so much @horchler! I didn't really understand fully what the documentation was talking about with `deval(XINT,SOL,IDX)`. That clears it up for me! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The optional third argument to [`deval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deval.html) specifies which index of the solution to return. The index corresponds to the state vector (and initial conditions) and the output of your ODE integration function (`M`). In the particular case of your system, index `1` corresponds to the position and index `2` to the velocity. If you want output (and plot) both, you can omit the third argument:

```
...
y = deval(pos_solution,x);

% Plot of Position as a function of time
figure(3)
plot(x,y(1,:),'b',x,y(2,:),'r');
legend('Position','Velocity');
```